# ngChange on input changed by a select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a simple select input field where the user can choose an option:

```
        <select class="form-control" id="calc-masterbatchCode"
            ng-options="masterbatch as masterbatch.code for masterbatch in masterbatches"
            ng-model="$parent.materialTAB.selectedMasterbatch">
        </select>
```

as you can see the `selectedMasterbatch`object is stored in a parent controller.

Then i have a disabled input field in the order to show the property of the `selectedMasterBatch`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="calc-masterbatchPercentage"
                    ng-model="$parent.materialTAB.selectedMasterbatch.percentage"
                    ng-change="onMasterbPercentageChange()">
```

It works, but the problem is the `ngChange`directive:
because it doesn't fire the `onMasterbPercentageChange` function when the user select another masterbatch.

The only way to fire that function is to type something manually into the `calc-masterbatchParcentage`input field.

My goal is:
the user select a masterbatch, then he can see the masterbatch's property (the percentage) into the disabled input field and, when this one change, the `onMasterbPercentageChange`function is fired.

[image]

Comment: If you could make a demo of this would be better

Comment: I got it now!! Why don't call ng-change in `<select>`?

Comment: Btw.. are you sure you can access this function this way or is it in `$parent`?

Comment: @developer033 i don't want call it in the select because give me less flexibility in the future when i will implement new features. the function is located in the child controller and yes i can access in it because im in the child controller so that function is related with it.

Comment: Accordongly to Docs you can't `use ng-change` on `disable/readonly` inpunts -> *It will not be evaluated: if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: @developer033 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngChange` directive doesn't work on *disable/readonly* inputs, because it's only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model. So, since you're changing the value programmatically and not typing anything to this model, it doesn't calls `ngChange`

Here is more one part extracted from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

  ### ngChange will not be evaluated:

if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed

if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null

**if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value**

So, to achieve what you want you must *move* your `ng-change` to your `<select>`.

I hope it helps.